# android nine patch text color change

Tags: android, button, nine-patch, rollover

i have a button defined as Nine Patch like this:

```
<Button     android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/matita"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="@string/menu_help" />
```

In this button there is a text, for example "MY TEXT" this text have a black color. My issue is, when the button is pressed i want to change the text color simply. How i can do it?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)

**drawable/textColor.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/testcolor1"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor2" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor3" />
    <item android:color="@color/testcolor5"/>
</selector>
```

and then apply this to your `Button`

```
<Button     
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/matita"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:text="@string/menu_help"
    android textColor="@drawable/textColor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a selector to do this.

In your drawable folder, create a file, for example dynamic_color_button, and write this into it:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

And then in your button, access it with textColor:

```
<Button     android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/matita"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/dynamic_color_button"
            android:text="@string/menu_help" />
```